# In Ext JS 4.1.1, how do I programmatically add items to a buttongroup

Tags: extjs, extjs4, items, buttongroup

In Ext JS 4.1.1, how do I programmatically add items to a buttongroup? If I add items as part of defining a buttongroup, it works, for eg:

```
Ext.define('company.ButtonGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.ButtonGroup',
    title: 'File',
    columns: 2,
    defaults: {
        scale: 'small'
    },
    items: [
            { text: 'New', iconCls: 'new16' },
            { text: 'Open', iconCls: 'open16' }
            ]
});
var fileButtongroup = Ext.create('company.ButtonGroup');
```

However, if I try to assign an array of items, it doesn't work. For eg:

```
var fileArr = [
            { text: 'New', iconCls: 'new16' },
            { text: 'Open', iconCls: 'open16' }
            ];
Ext.define('company.ButtonGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.ButtonGroup',
    title: 'File',
    columns: 2,
    defaults: {
        scale: 'small'
    }
});
var fileButtongroup = Ext.create('company.ButtonGroup');
fileButtongroup.items = fileArr;
```

Further, I don't see any `setItems()` method also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `items` array gets processed upon component initialization (in initComponent()).

If you want to add items to your button group after you create it, you should use the [add()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-add) method. By the way it works on any [Container](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container) class.